# How to find Key value from an object based on the value passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search

Thanks for your time.

I have the following object in JavaScript:

```
{
  "key1":"value1,value2,value3",
  "key2":"value4,value5,value6"
}
```

Now I want to parse for a specific value and if the value exists, I want to return the key associated with it. Suppose that I am passing 'value3', it should return `key1`; if passing `value5`, it should return me `key2` and so on.

What is the best way to implement it using Javascript, keeping in mind the execution time. I have tried using sting manipulation functions like `indexOf`, `substr`; but not most effective I believe.

TIA.

Comment: `indexOf` may fail if you have "value1,value22,value3" for `value2` so you likely need to first split the values by mapping them, and then use indexOf on the array instead. At that point, I guess a reverse-approach would be cleverer, by creating a key-value pair map where the key is the value and the value is the desired key.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different approach that will generate a map where the key is actually the value of your original `values` object.
The generated map will be a sort of fast lookup. Just to make things clear **this solution is efficient as long as you need to do a lot of lookups**. For a single, unique lookup this solution is the less efficient, since building the hashmap requires much more time than just looking up for a single value.
However, once the map is ready, acquiring values through keys will be incredibly fast so, if you need to **later** acquire **multiple values**, this solution will be more suitable for the use case.

This can be accomplished using `Object.entries` and `Object.values`. Further explanations are available in the code below.

The code below (despite not required) will also take care of avoiding `indexOf` with limit cases like searching 'value9' over 'value9999' which, on a regular string, would actually work with indexOf.

```js
const values = {
  "key1":"value1,value2,value3",
  "key2":"value4,value5,value6",
  "key3":"value444,value129839,value125390", // <-- additional test case.
  "key4": "value9" // <-- additional test case.
};

const map = Object.entries(values).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  // If the value is invalid, return the accumulator.
  if (!value) return acc;
  // Otherwise, split by comma and update the accumulator, then return it.
  return value.split(',').forEach(value => acc[value] = key), acc;
}, {});

// Once the map is ready, you can easily check if a value is somehow linked to a key:
console.log(map["value444"]); // <-- key 3
console.log(map["value9"]); // <-- key 4
console.log(map["Hello!"]); // undefined
```

Comment: [Obviously](https://jsperf.com/so56079346/4), 1000 records is not enough to outperform the others. Without even faint shadow of trolling, do you really believe it can be faster at some point?

Comment: You didn’t get my point: if you don’t need to find a single key but multiple ones it will significantly improve due to the fact that the complexity is reduced. If you need to look for a lot of keys, that method is way more efficient than a regular find due to indexing.

Comment: Now I see, and I have to agree with you, for searching 2 values O(n) would be the whole lot faster than O(n2), especially, on the large input data.

Answer (score 2):

To me, the fastest and most concise way of doing that would be the combination of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) thrown against source object [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const src={"key1":"value1,value2,value3","key2":"value4,value5,value6"};

const getAkey = (obj, val) => (Object.entries(obj).find(entry => entry[1].split(',').includes(val)) || ['no match'])[0];

console.log(getAkey(src, 'value1'));
console.log(getAkey(src, 'value19'));
```

*p.s.* while `filter()`, or `reduce()`, or `forEach()` will run through the entire array, `find()` stops right at the moment it finds the match, so, if performance matters, I'd stick to the latter

Comment: I don't think this wins for conciseness.

Comment: was there a shorter one?

Comment: ...even if there possibly can be one, I doubt it will be faster at the same time

Comment: Without splitting the values, I am sceptical about the accuracy here. Say you got 'value55' on first array and 'value5' on second, test for 'value5' will return first array instead of the actual answer. So the answer is incorrect, right?

Comment: Hope, no other concerns now?

Comment: Now it doesn't and it is worth an upvote, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your search, you can use `indexOf` after looping through your object.
Here's an old school method:

```js
var obj = {
  "key1":"value1,value2,value3",
  "key2":"value4,value5,value6"
}

function search (str) {
  for (var key in obj) {
var values = obj[key].split(',');
if (values.indexOf(str) !== -1) return key
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(search('value1'))
console.log(search('value6'))
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()` with `filter()` method and get the index 0 of the returned array.

```js
var obj = {
  "key1":"value1,value2,value3",
  "key2":"value4,value5,value6"
}

function search (str) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
   const values = obj[key].split(',');
    if (values.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
     return key
    }
  })[0]
}

console.log(search('value1'))
console.log(search('value6'))
```

Comment: This will fail for `"value1,value2,value33"` if you look for `value3`.

Comment: @briosheje OP hasn't mentioned it has to be exact match. They have to clarify what should happen in that situation. `indexOf` looks like a safer option

Comment: @adiga I think it's implicit, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating over each value in your object and then splitting the value on each comma, then checking if the value is in the returned array like so:

```js
const myObj = {"key1":"value1,value2,value3","key2":"value4,value5,value6"}
 

function findKeyByValue(obj, value) {
    for (var key in myObj) {
     const valuesArray = myObj[key].split(',')
        if (valuesArray.includes(value)) {
            return key
        }
    }
}

const key = findKeyByValue(myObj, 'value5') // returns 'key2'
console.log(key)
```

EDIT: Changed loop for efficiency, and extracted code to function

Comment: `return` won't do exactly what expected here, though the approach is likely correct.

Comment: `return` will stop the `forEach()`, will it not? That is my desired outcome, anyway.

Comment: No, it will not. If you remove the `return`, the snippet will do exactly the same, the function inside does an explicit or implicit return for each iteration. A `forEach` has no "conventional" way to stop, though you can throw an exception from it if you really want to.

Comment: @KobanDavis actually it doesn't, you can't "directly" break the foreach in that way, but still, it's a solution and it covers a whole lot of cases. I would only eventually add the case where a comma does not exist.

Comment: @briosheje `"a".split(",")` gives you a one-element array, there is no need for separate case.

Comment: @tevemadar huh, you're right, thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: @KobanDavis : `for` is so much slower than `find()` especially, on the large enough data sets, please, check out my answer for details

Comment: See runnable snippet (this kind of embedded thing is created with the `<>` button, by the way)

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg despite it might be slower, using `for..in` is still a feasible solution :). He just need to replace `return` with `break`.

Comment: @briosheje : having more lines of code doesn't make it look any better, in my humble opinion, of course

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg using `break` it won't actually make it terribly less performant than find: https://jsperf.com/so56079346 . Beware: I'm not saying it's better, I'm just saying that it's still a solution and, hence, it should be kept as it is.

Comment: (Do not give up, this kind of loop can use `break`)

Comment: @tevemadar fixed now, thanks for editing into a snippet, I wasn't sure how to do that before

Comment: @briosheje : let's agree to disagree, the larger your input data set, the more [noticeable](https://jsperf.com/so56079346/4) is the difference

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg http://prntscr.com/nmvc6l indeed, sounds like for..in is somewhat faster here. In any case, **don't get me wrong**, I **prefere the .find solution over that one**, I just feel that this answer should be kept as it is, since it's still a feasible solution ;)

Comment: @briosheje : *"I prefere the .find solution over that one"* ... upvotes are quite welcome, than ;)

Comment: @briosheje : than, I'm arguing with my only supporter :)

Answer (score 1):

Lodash has a function for this called [findKey](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#findKey) which takes the object and a function to determine truthiness:

```
obj = { 'key1': 'value1, value2, value3', 'key2': 'value4,value5,value6' }
_.findKey(obj, val => val.includes('value3'))
# 'key1'
_.findKey(obj, val => val.includes('value5'))
# 'key2'
```

Comment: Did I miss the `lodash` tag under the question?

Comment: Was reinventing the wheel listed? There is simply no requirement to only respond according to the tags listed in the question. From the help center: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: 'reinventing' basically requires one simple line of code (check out my answer) and doesn't require to carry the toolbox for inventing the wheels on you...

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Just uses Object.entries and filters to find the entries that contain the value you're looking for. (Can find more than one object that has the desired value too)

```js
var obj = {
 "key1": "value1,value2,value3",
 "key2": "value4,value5,value6"
};

var find = 'value2';
var key = Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v.split(',').includes(find))[0][0];

console.log(key);
```

Might want to check the return value of `Object.entries(obj).filter((o) => o[1].split(',').includes(find))` before trying to access it, in case it doesn't return anything. Like so:

```js
var obj = {
 "key1": "value1,value2,value3",
 "key2": "value4,value5,value6"
};

function findKey(objectToSearch, valueToFind) {
 var res = Object.entries(objectToSearch).filter(([key, value]) => value.split(',').includes(valueToFind));
 if(res.length > 0 && res[0].length > 0) {
  return res[0][0];
 }
 return false;
}

console.log(findKey(obj, 'value5'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) can be used to check whether a value is present in an array. [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can be used for iteration and checking for the match.

```js
function findKey(json, searchQuery) {
  for (var key of Object.keys(json)) if (json[key].split(',').includes(searchQuery)) return key;
}

const json = {
  "key1": "value1,value2,value3",
  "key2": "value4,value5,value6"
}

console.log(findKey(json, 'value5'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get what the desired key.

```js
const data = {
  "key1": "value1,value2,value3",
  "key2": "value4,value5,value6"
};

const searchStr = 'value3';

const foundProp = Object.entries(data).filter(x => x[1].indexOf(searchStr) !== -1);

let foundKey = '';

if (foundProp && foundProp.length) {
  foundKey = foundProp[0][0];
}

console.log(foundKey);
```